# MySQL: One database slave, multiple masters

Tags: mysql, replication, slave, master

My question is:

Am I able to have one database server as slave to more than one master servers with different databases. So for example:

- DB-Server-1 contains database Apple
- DB-Server-2 contains database Banana
- I want to replicate them to my DB-Server-3 as Apple-Slave and Banana-Slave

If I'm able, can you tell me how to achieve this with MySQL 5.7?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL jargon that is called *"multi-source replication"* and that is a supported configuration in MySQL 5.7.

The MySQL manual comes with a complete tutorial:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html

> MySQL Multi-Source Replication enables a replication slave to receive transactions from multiple sources simultaneously. Multi-source replication can be used to:
>
> - back up multiple servers to a single server,
> - to merge table shards,
> - consolidate data from multiple servers to a single server.
>
> Multi-source replication does **not implement any conflict detection or resolution** when applying the transactions, and those tasks are left to the application if required. In a multi-source replication topology, a slave creates a replication channel for each master that it should receive transactions from.

etc.